# How to Store base64 image on server which is in php variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a base64 image to server so I converted it into image but it not getting uploaded on the server. The error I am getting while uploading the image is:

> Notice: Undefined index: 584fb34801024.png in
>   /home/dev/public_html/wp-content/plugins/paypal-frontend-registration/advertise_step_three.php on line 45 {"success":0,"message":"Server error. Could not upload."}

Here is the code I am trying:

```
$sign_img=$_POST['hdn_sign_img'];
$sign_img=str_replace('\"','',$sign_img);
$imageData = $sign_img;
list($type, $imageData) = explode(';', $imageData);
list(,$extension) = explode('/',$type);
list(,$imageData)      = explode(',', $imageData);
$fileName = uniqid().'.'.$extension;
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData);

$data = file_put_contents($fileName, $imageData);
var_dump($data);

$target = '/home/dev/public_html/wp-content/uploads';
$result = move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[$fileName], $target);

if($result){
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Upload Successful.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Server error. Could not upload.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES[$fileName]` - this makes no sense; the keys inside the $_FILES array don’t change just because you define a unique filename in a variable. The _target_ of the moving operation is where you want to make use of your generated unique filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to store it in a file without using the most common PHP uploading method, you can use `file_put_contents()`.

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/filename.ext', $imageData);
```

And voila. It's saved to your server.

#### Example from PHP.net

Here's an example for `move_uploaded_file()`

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
   if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

#### Some reading

- [PHP.net - file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [PHP.net - file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: I want to pass the filename dynamically

Comment: put contents will write data on file. I want to create a new image file when uploaded on server

Comment: Ahh.. I misunderstood. In that case simply use [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)